# How to hide Snapchat best friends list

Tags: ios, privacy

Actually how can we hide the best friends list in snapchat without unblocking friends bc unblocking them making them disappear from my snapchat friends list so we need to re-add them everytime we do.

Comment: @JashJacob Make that a answer and provide references/Source.

Comment: @JashJacob I've tried to find some tricks but yea it all failing and silly they ask me like chat a lot to some other unimportant friends just to make the fake best friends so the one I hide won't appear at the top but damn what for is that best friend feature, no privacy .

Comment: @user91747 I'd suggest you to create another account on snapchat to snap your other friends.

Comment: @JashJacob I just wonder why snapchat never thinks that the user of the app is not always common people, so they won't like their name to appear in public while they're talking to fans, omg RIP Snapchat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to "delete" best friends, but a simple fix is to block the person you sont want on your list which will reset you and their chatting score to 0. Making them not one of your best friends after blocking them make sure to unblock them and they will return to your contacts but NOT your best friend list.

Comment: I've tried deleted some but when i want them back as my friwnd i have to add them back and the sad thing is i cant control when the person i wanna keep secret will come up to the list,

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide the best friends list in snapchat. It's a feature from snapchat and the list is provided from the snapchat's servers. So even if you hide it on your application, it will be visible for others for whom the data will be directly served from the Snapchat servers.

According to the snapchat [support](https://support.snapchat.com/a/bestfriends), Best Friends are updated regularly and represent the friends you Snap with most frequently. They are selected automatically by a magical *Snapchat friendship algorithm.*

There isn't anything much you can do about this. Other than blocking the users for a random period of time to remove their names from the list.

Comment: So sad, less smart app

Comment: @user91747 I don't really think it's a problem. If it's bothering you much, You should try other clone apps. Maybe give Facebook's slingshot a try!

Comment: It's not that easy to get my idol notice other social media, hmmm but thanks hash ure helping a lot ..,,